# Are there any iOS SSH terminal apps that support truecolor (i.e., 24 bit color)?

Tags: terminal, ssh, color

There are quite a few capable SSH terminal client apps in the App Store — Termius, Blink, Prompt, etc..

Do any of them support truecolor? This is also known as 24-bit color. It represents millions of colors as opposed to 256 colors.

As far as I can tell, this [gist on truecolor](https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728) has the closest thing thing I can find to a current, authoritative list of which terminal clients do and don’t support truecolor. I don’t see any iOS SSH clients on that list, sadly.

Comment: What is it you need?  Ability to specify the exact right shade of pink for your text, or ability for the host to send more detailed ascii art?

Comment: The former. I want emacs on a remote machine in a terminal window to use exactly the same colors as emacs running as a GUI on my local machine, which uses 24 bit color. One reason is that none of the standard themes, with 256 colors, allow reading all text in magit buffers.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out [Termius](https://www.termius.com) supports 24-bit color, as does [Secure ShellFish](https://secureshellfish.app)

Comment: I couldn't find any information on Termius' truecolor support. Do you speak from firsthand experience or is there a link you could share?

Comment: Yes, I have used it regularly on iOS. It works. And I emailed support and they said on March 10, 2020, "Yes, we do support true color (24-bit) in the desktop, iOS and Android apps."